# Upgrading to [powershell-v4.0]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are two tags for PowerShell 4.0:

- [powershell-v4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v4.0) (734)
- [powershell-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-4.0) (34)

The preferred format for other version-specific PowerShell tags is to include the v-prefix, namely:

- [powershell-v1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v1.0) (121)
- [powershell-v2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v2.0) (3261)
- [powershell-v3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v3.0) (2046)
- [powershell-v5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v5.0) (249)

I don’t personally care whether there’s a “v” or not – but we should be consistent about which tagging convention we’re using. None of those tags have alternate formats – in this case, the [powershell-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-4.0) tag should be retagged and/or synonymies with [powershell-v4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v4.0).

Comment: The *v* should be dropped from all tags.

Answer (score 27):

## Let's get rid of the `v`

Think about it. When you say Powershell (X), you don't say `Powershell Version Four Point Zero` - you say `Powershell 4.0`.  The `v` is unnecessary, as there's just about nothing else that that `4.0` can mean.

Let's switch them all to [powershell-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-4.0) style.

Comment: Meh, let's actually get rid of the *version* and just use [tag:powershell]

Comment: @TylerH that's a very bad idea, it removes valuable information about the question. Would you also remove [c++-11], [c++-14], [c++-17] etc?

Comment: @Tyler no, different versions of PowerShell have different capabilities and features, so removing the version number altogether would take away information from the questions that is needed to correctly answer it. If it's not version specific, we can use the plain ol' PowerShell tag.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Don't be ridiculous; different languages are different, I would in general not do any action for one language that I might do for another.

Answer (score 22):

Well for the sake of consistency, I changed the 34 questions of `powershell-4.0` to be `powershell-v4.0`, but whoever has the power to batch-update 6000 questions to be in a different tag can surely remove the `v` from all of them if they so desire.

Comment: +1 for the consistency.  Hopefully we can remove those `v`s soon.

Comment: I renamed the 5 tags, and got rid of the v from all. (cc @Cullub).