# Cleaning up PowerShell tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

This question was posted a couple of years ago and it looks like *some* cleanup was done:

*[Upgrading to [powershell-v4.0]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342967/upgrading-to-powershell-v4-0)*

However, here are the current numbers:

```
╔══════════════════╦═════════╗
║ TAG              ║ COUNT   ║
╠══════════════════╬═════════╣
║ powershell       ║ 76,761  ║
║ powershell-1.0   ║ 134     ║
║ powershell-2.0   ║ 3,932   ║
║ powershell-3.0   ║ 2,858   ║
║ powershell-4.0   ║ 1,482   ║
║ powershell-5.0   ║ 664     ║
║ powershell-v5.1  ║ 58      ║
║ powershell-6.0   ║ 18      ║
║ powershell-v6.0  ║ 56      ║
╚══════════════════╩═════════╝
```

It looks like the simplest course of action would be to merge [powershell-v6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v6.0) into [powershell-6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-6.0) and rename [powershell-v5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v5.1) to [powershell-5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-5.1).

Any thoughts on [powershell-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-core)?

After discussion, I think this is the current proposal...

```
╔══════════════════╦════════╦══════════════════════════════════╗
║ TAG              ║ COUNT  ║ ACTION                           ║
╠══════════════════╬════════╬══════════════════════════════════╣
║ powershell       ║        ║                                  ║
║ powershell-1.0   ║ 134    ║                                  ║
║ powershell-2.0   ║ 3,932  ║                                  ║
║ powershell-3.0   ║ 2,858  ║                                  ║
║ powershell-4.0   ║ 1,482  ║                                  ║
║ powershell-5.0   ║ 664    ║                                  ║
║ powershell-v5.1  ║ 58     ║ Merge into powersehll-5.0?       ║
║ powershell-core  ║ 179    ║ Rename powershell-core-6.0       ║
║ powershell-6.0   ║ 18     ║ Merge into powershell-core-6.0   ║
║ powershell-v6.0  ║ 56     ║ Merge into powersehll-core-6.0   ║
╚══════════════════╩════════╩══════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: [powershell-core] is something different from [powershell] in general, so it can stay. Like [other similar merges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385027/2370483) the rest should be merged

Comment: Powershell Core isn't Powershell v6 (and now v7)?

Comment: Apparently it is. So I would merge those two to [powershell-core], and the rest to [powershell]

Comment: But eventually we will have Powershell v7 questions. Are you proposing [tag:powershell-core-6.0] and [tag:powershell-core-7.0]?  I would lean towards removing the "core" designation.

Comment: The problem is [powershell] is purely a Windows thing, while [powershell-core] is for multiple OSes

Comment: ahh, good point.  But still, is there a need to differentiate between 6 and 7 I guess?

Comment: I'm not keen on version tags unless there's some demonstrable difference. I don't think there's a ton of difference in the versions TBH. It also leads to users tagging things with the specific versions and omitting the main tag that people watch

Comment: I can see both sides.  It is a problem. However, it's also a problem when I'm working in Powershell 5 and post a question that gets an answer which only applies to Powershell 6.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Isn't PowerShell replaced by PowerShell Core? (That is, the last version of PowerShell has already been released.)

Comment: Classic powershell ended with v5.1.  Version 6 is multiplatform and called "Core" and will continue the version numbers.  That's my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR;

While [@iRon's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415668) correctly points out the differences between **Windows PowerShell** and **PowerShell Core** as well as why both the [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) and [powershell-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-core) tags should remain, I disagree with its assertion that PowerShell's version-specific tags should be burned. I would instead propose the following:

- Keep all of the version-specific tags, as well as the base [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) and [powershell-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-core) tags
- Merge the `v#` and `#` version-variants together (e.g. [powershell-6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-6.0) and [powershell-v6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v6.0) are the same thing)

---

### Why it matters for Windows PowerShell

While there are not many breaking changes from version to version, if you are locked into a specific version the built-in cmdlets and functions change and code which works in later versions will not work if those built-ins don't exist in an earlier version. If the asker is in a PowerShell 4.0 environment, code which was written for 5 may not work without minor to major modification, depending on what needs to be reimplemented. While this sounds familiar for any language continuing to be developed, PowerShell is a bit special in that:

- The base installed version changes depending on the installed version of your operating system.

  - This is less of a concern moving forward since 5.1 is essentially frozen for feature work, so 5.1 should be the Windows' OS default for some time.
  - Note that **Windows PowerShell 4.0** is still the pre-installed version for the soon-to-be-EOL'd **Windows Server 2012R2** OS.
- ***Windows*** **PowerShell 5.1** and earlier can only have a single version installed, which cannot be downgraded outside of a rollback.

  - This restriction does not apply to PowerShell Core versions (6+) as they can be installed side-by-side and the OS does not carry a dependency on it.
- Microsoft does not maintain PowerShell documentation for versions older than 5.1 on MSDN, meaning one should be especially knowledgeable in older versions when answering questions pertaining to those versions.

A major point of tags is to connect experts with questions they can answer. I and others can of course filter on [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) or [powershell-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-core). However, if a question is for [powershell-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-3.0), I **immediately** know to avoid suggesting cmdlets that were not available in version 3. From the other side, a candidate answerer who did not use PowerShell until version 5 or later may be unaware that some of their code uses functions or cmdlets that were not available in that earlier version. This can result in a wholly incorrect answer that does not work within the presented scope. Sure, you can say the question body should mention the version but the majority of questions in the PowerShell tags I come across don't mention specific versions outside of the use of version-specific tags, and such a statement de-legitimizes the use of tags in the first place. (rhetorical: Why not standardize on the single [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) tag and rely on the question body to give any runtime context at all?)

If you are not well-versed in an older version, you would need to maintain parallel installations of Windows to test code against older versions of PowerShell, with one exception.

> **Note:** The next claim juxtaposes the [PowerShell documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7#-version-powershell-version), which is incorrect on the matter. The only earlier PS version you can explicitly set is `2.0`. This parameter has no effect in **PowerShell Core**.

[powershell-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-2.0) is a different beast which carried a different SLA to its later versions. **Windows PowerShell** versions needed to maintain V2 compliance across OS releases for several years, and continues to do so at this time of writing. Questions tagged for **Windows PowerShell v2** are (or were) especially important to maintain a distinction for due to this. For the same reason, PowerShell v2 is the only version for which you can tell **Windows PowerShell** to run an older version of the engine and have it actually run in that same version (executing against any other previous version silently runs the latest engine). While this does make v2 code more testable than v3 or v4 at present, compliance with v2 was still a restriction of many PS questions and remains important for historical classification of such questions and answers.

### Why it matters for PowerShell Core

When it comes to **PowerShell Core**, organizations will often standardize on LTS releases of PowerShell Core. Answers for these questions should still be limited to solutions for those versions. For example, 7.0 and 7.2 are both LTS releases of PowerShell. Someone locked to 7.0 in their environment will be unable to use answers using features presented in PowerShell 7.1 and later. The same will
apply when 7.3 exits preview status and eventually when the next LTS release comes out.

There is admittedly less use here for non-LTS versions but it seems untenable to suggest only using LTS version tags.

---

Therefore, for historical classification *and* in cases where users may be locked into a specific version (see the above about Windows Server 2012R2 which is not yet EOL'd), version-specific tags are still useful. They may not be as useful for classifying newer questions, especially as older Windows versions remain stagnant and fall further out of support, but removing them from appropriate questions would only serve to harm the content to which these questions are bound.

Instead, we should merge or synonymize the duplicate version tags (like the `v` and non-`v` variants denoting a specific PS version) and clean up questions which incorrectly use incorrect version specific tags. Is this as simple as burning the version-specific tags? **No**. But I believe it is the *best* way to taxonomize questions relating to particular versions of PowerShell.

Answer (score -1):

Please, keep it simple.
There are actually two major versions of PowerShell:

- **Windows PowerShell**
- **PowerShell** (Core)

[**Windows PowerShell**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell)
Windows PowerShell (up to version 5.1) only runs on Windows and there is virtually no development on it.
[Quote from the PowerShell team:](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-team-2021-investments/#microsoft-update)

> In 2021, we’re working to publish PowerShell 7 to the Microsoft Download Catalog and to Microsoft Update. On the Download Catalog, you’ll be able to use application deployment tools like SCCM, WSUS, and Intune to easily install and update PS7. And with Microsoft Update, you’ll receive updates to PS7 right alongside Windows Update, even if you had installed PowerShell 7 originally via MSI.

[**PowerShell**](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/overview) (Core)

> PowerShell Core is a cross-platform (Windows, Linux, and macOS) automation and configuration tool/framework that works well with your existing tools and is optimized for dealing with structured data (e.g. JSON, CSV, XML, etc.), REST APIs, and object models. It includes a command-line shell, an associated scripting language and a framework for processing cmdlets.

In all minor versions from the start of (Windows) PowerShell there are hardly any breaking changes, meaning that questions related to (minor) PowerShell versions are rare and therefor usually already clearly mentioned in the content or even the title.
In fact, the different PowerShell Tag versions (as e.g. [[powershell-2.0] [powershell-3.0] [powershell-4.0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-2.0+powershell-3.0+powershell-4.0)) are more *misused* (to get more attention) than pinpointing a specific PowerShell issue related to a specific version only.

In other words, my advice is to bring all PowerShell version tags back to just two tags:

- **Windows-PowerShell**
- **PowerShell** (Core)

Note: [MSFT explicitly say that it is next version of PowerShell - Windows PowerShell version is 5 and PowerShell version was 6 and now 7.](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16728#issuecomment-1009580083)

Comment: There are thousands and thousands of PowerShell questions that are version-specific. Removing major-version PS tags will cause harm to those questions and the site. If your concern is misuse of version tags, cleanup should be your first step, not burnination.

Comment: Yep. Just `sudo apt-get install -y powershell` on Ubuntu (if .NET Core is already installed). The executable is `pwsh`.

Comment: Though scripts do not port over cleanly if they rely on aliases (e.g., listed by `Get-Alias | select Name, Definition, DisplayName | Sort-Object Definition, Name`). Ironically, some aliases that work on Windows, e.g. `ls`, `cp`, and `sort`, are not present on Linux. The system ones will result in errors during execution, e.g. *"/usr/bin/sort: cannot read: Definition,: No such file or directory"*. Cmdlet [Sort-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Sort-Object) works as expected.

Comment: @TylerH, I have started a new discussion: [What is the use of version tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415770/1701026) based on your comment.

Comment: FYI, tags are always all lower-case and fewer than 35 characters, so the tags would be `windows-powershell` and `powershell-core` (or `powershell`). You're running into the same issue with PS as others have with .NET and its renaming of .NET Core to just .NET in version 5 and the simultaneous lessening of importance for .NET Framework. See e.g. [Untangling the twisted \[.net\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407441/215552)