# Should requirements be specified solely via tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Related: [What is the use of version tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415770/what-is-the-use-of-version-tags)

I've recently noticed a few cases where the questioner has specific requirements that they've expressed solely by adding tags to the question. For example, they might ask a C++ question that they want a C++14 answer to, but instead of saying so in the question, they slap a [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) tag on the question and get aggrieved (even downvoting) if someone posts an answer that utilizes features of C++17 or higher. Or they might post what reads as an interesting question about the rationale behind a language rule or restriction - but they've added a [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag, since what they *actually* want is a recitation of chapter and verse.

It's not that I have a problem with such questions; retrocomputing is interesting, people have to deal with obsolescent systems, and language-lawyering is often fun, although I find it a bit sterile when not looking at implementation divergence or nonconformance. So I'm subscribed to quite a few old-version tags as well as [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer), and don't particularly wish to change that. However it is easy to skip over tags when reading a question, since they are deemphasized in the UI. Also, the existence of such questions would imply that one could have two or more questions with verbatim identical title and body, that differ only in tags, which seems a bit odd.

Is this an acceptable use of tags, or should we expect questions to contain all relevant restrictions within the body (or title) of the question itself?

Comment: My position is that everything conveyed in the tags should *also* be mentioned in the body of the question. If it's not, and you feel you can accurately judge the intention of the author, you can always submit an edit that corrects that problem.

Answer (score 12):

On the one hand, I can understand the discontent of the asker. In their eyes, they specified a tag with a version for a reason, and you (I assume, or maybe somebody else, but it doesn't really matter) disregarded their specific tag and assumed a more general one.

On the other hand, seeing how often seemingly random tags are slapped on questions, especially by new users, I can see why somebody who tries to answer might generalize tags that are not justified in the text.

As far as I know, there are no explicit rules for mentioning tags. In this situation, everybody is expected to use their best judgment: if you are generalizing a tag, mention it and provide the reasoning behind it in your answer. You could even preemptively ask in comments.

If this situation is specific to one or a couple of users, try to explain to them the point of view of the answerer, who sees erroneously used version-specific tags daily and is consciously blindsided by them. Explain that while it is not strictly required, simply mentioning that the answer needs to be version-specific will save them the hassle of dealing with undesired answers and clarify the question for those who want to help them.

Comment: The only rule for mentioning tags is to not mention them in the title of the question. But even that isn't followed often.

Answer (score 6):

**Tag [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) is unambiguous, it doesn't require any accompanying text in the question itself.**

This tag has an exact meaning: the answers must cite the relevant specification.

**Language version tags [c++-xx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-xx) are ambiguous. If you're limited to a certain language version, the question must explicitly say so *in addition* to having the tag.**

There doesn't seem to be a consensus on what those tags mean. I've seen them used as:

- Lower limit on version. "This question uses/discusses features from C++-__".

  Example: a question tagged [c++-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-11) about `std::enable_if` and SFINAE could benefit from a C++20 answer about `concept`s.
- Upper limit on version. "The answers must use C++-__ or older."

  This is the meaning you had in mind.

Some users misuse the version tags for following:

- The current standard they're targeting, when they don't mind switching to a newer one.
- Tag spam with all language versions they know.

**If you decide ignore OP's requirements, explicitly say so in the answer.**

Sometimes you might want to ignore OP's requirements:

- If there's an especially clever answer in a newer language version, I would post it regardless, explicitly mentioning the version it targets. Even better if your answer also provides an alternative in OP's preferred version.
- If [language-laywer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-laywer) is misused, the answer should explain why it's the case. Alternatively, consider convincing OP to remove the tag before posting your answer.

Comment: "Tag language-lawyer is unambiguous, it doesn't require any accompanying text in the question itself." So, hypothetically, could there be two questions with identical title and body, that differ only in tags?

Comment: @ecatmur In theory - perhaps yes. In practice, a `language-lawyer` question will likely explain why the author finds the simple answer insufficient, e.g. by demonstrating different behavior in existing implementations.

Comment: @ecatmur No, because the Stack Overflow software flat out does not allow multiple questions with the same title, for some reason.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "will likely explain why the author finds the simple answer insufficient" - I'm asking about the case where it doesn't. Would it be correct to edit the question to clarify that the author is asking for language-lawyer answers?

Comment: @ecatmur IMO such edit would be unnecessary, but it doesn't hurt either. I browse those (C++/language-lawyer) questions a lot, and I almost have never seen this tag being ignored. Perhaps once or twice by a newcomer.

Comment: @ecatmur: The general phrasing and presentation of a language-lawyer question should make it pretty clear that it's asking about what exactly the ISO standard has to say.  e.g. that their research-effort included looking at some standardese already.  If not, *that's* what should be improved (perhaps only by the OP if it's a low quality question an editor can't whip into shape).  The intent of the [language-lawyer] tag   usually doesn't need to be spelled out; the way the question is asked should make it clear that's the kind of answer they desire. (Plus the tag itself is a big sign.)

Answer (score -4):

I tend to generally completely ignore tags as in the vast majority of cases they are completely irrelevant to the question being asked, appearing to be just selected to create as broad a visibility to the question as possible. IOW they're intended as clickbait and little else.

Just look at the frequency of Python related questions being tagged with "Java"... Or historically Javascript related questions being tagged with "Java" (though that may have been in part confusion as many people still think that Javascript is Java).

So if you limit your question to just a selection of tags (after all, your 'requirements' are often the entire question), it makes no sense to me.

Comment: I do consider them when I have a listing of questions in front of me. Not much use for me to try and answer .NET questions even though the site does like to pelt them my way :) That's the main purpose of tags for me - to drag the right people in and come look (or rather: keep it out of sight from people without the necessary knowledge?). After that, they lose most value. Answering questions is a fair bit of reading between the lines anyway, people don't tend to really ask what they want to know but more of an approximation of it.

Comment: This answer surprises me. It's the complete opposite for me: my entire interaction with questions on Stack Overflow is based foremost on tags. When I encounter incorrectly tagged questions (which happens, but not as frequently as this question implies), I correct them. To claim that tags are “in the vast majority of cases … completely irrelevant” is, in my experience, just factually false.